# Connecting phone earpiece to laptop through bluetooth possible?

Tags: bluetooth, peripherals, ear-piece

is there anyway to connect a phone earpiece to be usable by the laptop through bluetooth or some other technology? (in other words "channeling" the sounds of the laptop to the product)

The product is [Plantronics ML10](http://www.plantronics.com/au/product/ml10) (I think it uses blue-tooth or something). I'm trying to connect it to a [Aspire 4937G](http://asia.cnet.com/product/acer-aspire-4937g-core-2-duo-t9550-processor-266ghz-4gb-ram-44781126.htm) running Windows Vista Home Premium sp2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although you'll need the third-party Bluetooth stack that came with the adapter. Once you've installed it and paired the device, it will show up in the audio devices control panel.